# How To Set Typeface To the setMessage Part Of An AlertDialog.Builder?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set a typeface to the message part of an AlertDialog.Builder. The following code only works for the title and buttons. I am not sure why the message font isn't the same?

Java Code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(MainActivity.this, R.style.MyAlertTheme));
                adb.setTitle("My App");
                adb.setMessage("Would you like to launch the calendar?"); //Typeface doesn't work for this. Why?

                adb.setPositiveButton("Open Calendar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, android.net.Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/time/")));
                    }
                })

                adb.create();
                adb.show();
```

Styles Code

```
<style name="MyAlertTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
```

Typeface Java Class

```
static class DefaultAppFont{
        static void setFontForApp(Context context, String typeFaceFieldName, String fontAssetName) {
            final Typeface myAppTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontAssetName);
            replaceFont(typeFaceFieldName, myAppTypeFace);
        }

        private static void replaceFont(String typeFaceFieldName, final Typeface newTypeFace) {
            try {
                final Field field = Typeface.class.getDeclaredField(typeFaceFieldName);
                field.setAccessible(true);
                field.set(null, newTypeFace);
            }catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

onCreate

```
DefaultAppFont.setFontForApp(getApplicationContext(), "MONOSPACE", "fonts/myFont.ttf");
```

Thanks!

Here is the error...

```
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(MainActivity.this, R.style.MyAlertTheme));
                adb.setTitle("My App");
                adb.setMessage("Would you like to launch the calendar?");

                adb.setPositiveButton("Open Calendar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, android.net.Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/time/")));
                    }
                })

                AlertDialog dialog = adb.create();
                TextView tv = dialog.findViewById(R.id.message);
                Typeface tf = ResourcesCompat.getFont(MainActivity.this, R.font.myFont);
                tv.setTypeface(tf);
                adb.show();
```

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: use `android:fontFamily`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `android:fontFamily` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should get text view from Dialog and set custom typeface

```
AlertDialog dialog = adb.create() 
TextView textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
Typeface font = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.myFont)
textView.setTypeface(font);
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that didn't work. All it does is crash my app. I keep getting a null pointer exception.